# Google Contacts and Google Plus properties

Tags: python, django, google-plus, google-contacts-api

I am using a Python application to access my Google Contacts and retrieve their information. My current problem, however, is not of programming, it's conceptual.

I noticed that in the past fields like the cell phone and home address were part of the Google Contact. However, it seems that now the Google Contacts only contain email/groups, and all the extra information such as cell phone and address is part of the Google Plus profile.

Therefore, I am assuming that in order to obtain someone's full contact information, including phone number and address, I need to use the Google Plus API and not the Google Contacts API. Would this be a fair assumption?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I cannot speak to the state of the Google Contacts API, but for more information on the person resource for the Google+ API, you can check https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people.

One thing to note: these fields will only be populated when the user lists them as Public on their Google+ profile.